# Convert large array of floats to colors and write to binary efficiently

Tags: python, numpy, memory, colors, netcdf

I am working with large NetCDF4 files (about 1 GB and up but less than my 8 GB memory for now). 99% of the time the data type will be a float32. I want to map these values to an array of RGB colors which I will then write to a binary file to be read by another application for viewing. Because I only need 1 byte for each R, G, and B, I want to have an array of np.uint8 to represent this. In the end the array will take up 25% less space than the floats. However, as the original data is big, I don't want to keep both the original data and the color data in memory at the same time. For now I provide a color for the low value and the color for the high value. The problem is that in my program for a short period time, the color data consists of floats instead of np.uint8, which leads to taking up 3 times as much memory as the original data. Is there a way to skip the float conversion or at least only have one float in memory so that I don't take up this much memory? I have provided relevant code below:

```
from netCDF4 import Dataset
import numpy as np
import dask.array as da
import gc
import time
import sys
# Read file path
file_path = sys.argv[1]
# Default colors is blue for low and red for high
lowColor = np.array([0, 0, 255], dtype=int)
highColor = np.array([255, 0, 0], dtype=int)
data = Dataset(file_path)
allVariables = data.variables
# Sometimes we have time_bnds, lat_bnds, etc.
# Keep anything that doesn't have 'bnds'
varNames = list(filter(lambda x: 'bnds' not in x, list(allVariables.keys())))
# Remove the dimensions
varNames = list(filter(lambda x: x not in data.dimensions, varNames))
var = varNames[0]
flattened = allVariables[var][:].flatten()
origShape = allVariables[var].shape
if isinstance(flattened, np.ma.core.MaskedArray):
    flattened = flattened.filled(np.nan)
# Find the minimum value and the range of values.
# Using these two we can make a percentage of how
# far 'up' each value and simply convert colors
# based on that. Because there's a chance of the data
# having NaNs, I can't use ptp().
lowVal = np.nanmin(flattened)
ptp = np.nanmax(flattened) - lowVal
# Subtract the min from each value and divide by ptp
# and add a dimension for dot product later.
percents = ((flattened - lowVal) / ptp)[np.newaxis, :]
# Remove flattened from memory as it is not needed anymore
flattened = None
gc.collect()
# Calculate the color difference
diff = (highColor - lowColor)[np.newaxis, :].T
# Do the dot product to create a list of colors
# Transpose so each color is each row. Also
# add the low color
colors = lowColor + np.dot(diff, percents).T # All floats here
# Round each value and cast to uint8 and finally reshape to
# the original data
colors = np.round(colors).astype(np.uint8)
colors = colors.reshape(origShape + (3,))
colors.tofile('colors_' + allVariables[var].name + '.bin')
```

Comment: I not sure if it will be much help, but often numpy functions will have an option "inplace" which if set to true will edit the matrix rather than creating a new one. If you don't need a matrix after an operation, see if you could do it in place to save on memory.